# SMTPServerDisconnected at /resetpassword/ Connection unexpectedly closed in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, smtp

I am trying to setup my smtp configuration to work with reset password builtin in Django.
I works fine with google smtp, but when i tried to add an email from my domain server i got this error after taking too mush time.

SMTPServerDisconnected at /resetpassword/
Connection unexpectedly closed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this to the setting.py file
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER